# I want to do pagination by categories by getting cat variable

Tags: php

The number of pages is displaying but I get the same record on page 2 which I have on page 1

I tried to write cat variable but it doesn't work

```php
<?php

include("connection.php");

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    $page = 1;
}

$productPerPage = 6;
$startNum = ($page - 1)* $productPerPage ; // (2-1) * 3 

require_once("connection.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where category='".$_GET['cat']."' limit ".$startNum.",".$productPerPage) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(isset($_GET['cat']))
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where category='".$_GET['cat']."'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

```php
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where category='".$_GET['cat']."'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$noOfPages = ceil($count / $productPerPage);
echo '<p>';
for($i = 1;$i<=$noOfPages;$i++)
{
    echo'<li><a href="index.php?page='.$i.(isset($_GET['cat'])?'&cat='.$_GET['cat']:'').'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

}

?>
</div>
```

Same data is coming on page no 1 and 2.

Comment: If i recall correctly when you use limit with two params those are start and end. If i'm right you're missing a var. Let's call it $endNum with values = $startNum + $productPerPage; and use it instead of ".$productPerPage) or die in your first query on the db.

Comment: When `$_GET['cat']` is passed, you're ignoring the pagination and overwriting `$result` with _all_ of the rows from the given category.

Comment: @Patrick Q what should i replace?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do.  I'd say probably put your first `mysqli_query()` call inside the `if` block and remove the one that's there.  But I'm not sure what you're wanting to do if `$_GET['cat']` is _not_ set.

Comment: @Patrick Q show me in coding form please?

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Q it worked

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where category='".$_GET['cat']."' limit $startNum,$productPerPage") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}else{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from products limit $startNum, $productPerPage") or die(mysqli_error($con));

}
```